# UPDATE query using record counts (DCount) from another table

Tags: ms-access

Anyone please help me to solve this query?

I have two tables one table(Act_Tkt) contain fields like below

```
PName | Severity1 | Severity2
_____________________________

AAAA  |           |
```

Another table (Data) has some fields like below

```
PName | Severity | Type | Group | Create_Date
_____________________________________________
```

Now i need to update the count of records from (Data) to Act_Tkt with below criteria for that particular PName

```
UPDATE Act_Tkt INNER JOIN Data ON Act_Ticket.PName = Data.PName 
SET Severity1 =
=DCount("[PName]","Data","[Severity] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [Group] <> 'Support' and [Create_Date]< #11/14/2013 16:00:00#")
```

I have used the above query but i am getting same number in all the rows in Act_Tkt.

Any advise will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `DCount()` then you don't need to do the INNER JOIN on [Data]. What you *do* need is something in the `DCount()` criteria that relates back to the current [Act_Tkt] row. (Currently your `DCount()` criteria string never changes from one row to the next, which is why you get the same value for every row.)

Try this instead:

```sql
UPDATE Act_Tkt
SET Severity1 = DCount("*","Data","[Severity] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [Group] <> 'Support' and [Create_Date]< #11/14/2013 16:00:00# and [PName]='" & [PName] & "'")
```